# Error: unexpected '}' in " }" when removing a column that has a 0 in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to remove columns that have a 0 in them.

I have this so far and nothing seems to be working.

```
for (r in 1:nrow(y)) {
  for (c in 1:ncol(y)) {
    if (y[r, c] == 0) {
      then y[,c] <- NULL
      r <- r-1
      c <- c-1
    }
  } 
}
```

I'm not sure about the last two lines - I figured that it might skip over something if it was removed at a certain point.

Thanks guys

Comment: you should remove `then`  right before `y[,c] <- NULL`

Comment: I now get: Error in if (y[r, c]) == 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Do you have NAs in your data

Comment: Nope, just 0s .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to be very clever with the `for` loop, but you're misunderstanding how iteration works in R. When your loop starts with `for (c in 1:ncol(y))`, as soon as that line is run the first time, `ncol(y)` will be evaluated, the `1:ncol(y)` sequence will be generated and saved, and each time through the loop `c` will take the next value.

Let's say `y` has 3 columns. As soon as the loop starts, `c` will be set up to be 1, then 2, then 3. If, when `c = 1` you end up deleting the first column, then you run `c <- c-1` to make `c` 0, *it doesn't matter* because R won't add 1 to `c` - you're not telling it `c = c+1` each time through the loop, you're told R `c` is one the first time, then `2` the second time. So `c` is 2 the second time and you've skipped the used-to-be-second-now-first column. And the next time through the loop `c` will be 3 and there is no third column anymore.

You also have a nesting issue. If `y[1, 1]` is 0, then the first column is removed, you set `c` and `r` to 0. Your inner loop hits the next iteration, and as explained above `c` will take the next value, 2. But we haven't completed the outer loop yet so `r` is still 0, and `y[0, 2]` will be your next test. But of course there is no 0 index.

*The better way*

R is vectorized. So, we'll (all at once) detect which columns have 0s, then we'll (all at once) remove them.

```
# detect columns with 0
col_has_0 = colSums(y == 0) >= 1
# remove them
y = y[, !col_has_0]
```

Comment: Hi Gregor, thanks for the reply. Does this not just look at the columns that sum to 0 and then delete those? In this case, I have values in the columns but have some missing data so the colSums would be >0 for all of them... also got this error "Error in `[.data.frame`(y, , !col_has_0) : undefined columns selected"

Comment: Ah I see the col_has_0 works but am still getting that error.. hmm

Comment: `colSums(y) == 0` would see which cols sum to 0. `colSums(y == 0)` counts the number of 0s in each column. `colSums` will work with a matrix, data frame, or tibble at the least. If you have some other object type I make no guarantees.